# HTTP or FTP for client/server application in java

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp, ftp

im Trying to Write a Windows client-server Version control application .
i've created two servers , one works with java socket ( java.net library ) to handling the requests ( login, signup and ... ) coming from client . and the other server is running on FTP protocol (using apache common net library) for serving my files .
and client is able to communicate with the first server over tcp socket and download or upload files to the second server using FTP .
but recently someone just told me that i should use HTTP instead of both . because HTTP in java in really easy to use for both communicating and FILE serving and most importantly is its able to traverse the NAT which now what im using is not able to do .

now im wondering is he right ? should i change my servers to use HTTP instead of TCP socket and FTP ? whats the benefit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some advantages of changing your protocol stack to HTTP:

- You can easily add security later (only a matter of a single 's')
- You don't have to do two servers, you can do all-in-one.
- At some point you could offer a browser-based access of you don't have the client installed / work of a decive where you *cannot* install it
- HTTP webapps (even those in java) are proven to scale very, very well. So once you have a lot of users, you're still good to go.
- There's a lot of helpful frameworks out there that can help you focus on the *what* instead of the *how*
- Most companies that allow outside-access at all will have HTTP/HTTPS open. FTP is more limited in most places.
- NAT traversal / Proxy traversal

and that's only the ones I came up with while typing :-)

Downsides:

- You have to start over. *But*: If you run into trouble, Stack Overflow is there to help you out.

Comment: +1 for your good answere . Is there any easy to learn library for http ? Couse im really thinking i need to change

Comment: If I had to learn that from scratch, I'd start with tomcat 8 and a simple webapp with some Annotation based servlets. Once you have basic understanding of how that works together, I'd check out Spring as a next step (if needed)

Comment: how about java websocket api ? can i use it ?

Comment: Websockets you could use as well - but for sending commands and receiving responses classic HTTP seems better.

Comment: how about file transmission ? which one is better for this purpose ?

Comment: Reagrdinf websocket vs plain HTTP? Again it's HTTP as that abstracts all the nasty details.